# Finding the day ahead after n days

Tags: java

I'm writing simple code in Java which is supposed to return the day after `n` days. But because I just started learning I'm having problem solving that. For now, I wrote that piece of code but I have no idea how to move forward.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        final String Mon = "Mon";
        final String Tue = "Tue";
        final String Wed = "Wed";
        final String Thu = "Thu";
        final String Fri = "Fri";
        final String Sat = "Sat";
        final String Sun = "Sun";
        
        String[] arr = {Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun};
        
        System.out.println("What day is today:");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String text = scanner.next();
        
        System.out.println("You want to know the day after how many days:");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        
        if(n>=7)
            n = n%7;
        
        int[]index = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5 ,6};
        
        String start;
        
        switch(text) {
        case Mon:
            start = arr[0];
            //int ind = index[0];
        case Tue:
            start = arr[1];
            //int ind = index[1];
        case Wed:
            start = arr[2];
        case Thu:
            start = arr[3];
        case Fri:
            start = arr[4];
        case Sat:
            start = arr[5];
        case Sun:
            start = arr[6];
        
        for(int i =0;i<n;i++) {
            String solution = arr[index[i]+i];
        }
        System.out.println(solution);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem by the way?

Comment: So the user would enter, for example, Tue and 8 and the output would be Wed?

Comment: @jarmod exactly as you said

Comment: @VeKe the problem is that it is not working. It returns random days and I have no idea how to fix it :/

Comment: OK, so you find the index associated with the entered day (Tue => 1), add the numbers of days entered to that index (modulo 7), and that gives you the index of the resulting day. Also, your code as written looks like it will not compile. You should fix that first.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I tried to do and I think I did it right. The problem I faced is how to write that statement in for() so I will get the right index of the wanted day

Comment: +1 to Jamod, fix your compile errors. Secondly, please know if you are using the switch-case correctly, it is free fall for you ; ideally use break in between

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I renamed `arr` to `daysList` and `n` to `numberOfDays`. Also,

- You do not need the index array
- You can get the index of today's day by iterating over the `daysList` array using a for loop as follows
- After getting the current index, we just need to add `numberOfDays` to the current index and get the index of the required day. (Please note, we have to do %7 here to bring back the index under 7).
- The updated code is below for your reference

  ```
   import java.util.Scanner;
   public class Main {
       public static void main(String[] args) {

           final String Mon = "Mon";
           final String Tue = "Tue";
           final String Wed = "Wed";
           final String Thu = "Thu";
           final String Fri = "Fri";
           final String Sat = "Sat";
           final String Sun = "Sun";

           String[] daysList = {Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun};

           System.out.println("What day is today:");
           Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
           String today = scanner.next();

           System.out.println("You want to know the day after how many days:");
           Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
           int numberOfDays = sc.nextInt();

           if(numberOfDays >= 7)
               numberOfDays = numberOfDays % 7;

           int ansDayIndex = 0;
           for(int dayIndex = 0; dayIndex < 7; ++dayIndex){
               if(daysList[dayIndex].equalsIgnoreCase(today)){
                   ansDayIndex = (dayIndex + numberOfDays) % 7;
                   break;
               }
           }

           System.out.println("The day after " + numberOfDays + " will be " + daysList[ansDayIndex]);
       }
   };
  ```

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to use switch-case , try using break in between
- Instead of forloop you can simply do like this

> ```
>   import java.util.Scanner;
>   public class Program {
>   public static void main(String[] args) {
>
>             
>             final String Mon = "Mon";
>             final String Tue = "Tue";
>             final String Wed = "Wed";
>             final String Thu = "Thu";
>             final String Fri = "Fri";
>             final String Sat = "Sat";
>             final String Sun = "Sun";
>             
>             String[] arr = {Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun};
>             
>             System.out.println("What day is today:");
>             Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
>             String text = scanner.next();
>             
>             System.out.println("You want to know the day after how many days:");
>             Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
>             int n = sc.nextInt();
>             
>             if(n>=7)
>                 n = n%7;
>             
>             int[]index = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5 ,6};
>             
>             int start=-99;
>             
>             switch(text) {
>             case Mon:
>                 start = 0;break;
>             case Tue:
>                 start = 1;break;
>             case Wed:
>                 start = 2;break;
>             case Thu:
>                 start = 3;break;
>             case Fri:
>                 start = 4;break;
>             case Sat:
>                 start = 5;break;
>             case Sun:
>                 start = 6;
>             }
>             
>             String solution = arr[(start+n)>=7?(start+n-7):(start+n)];
>         
>             System.out.println(solution);
>             }
>         }
> ```

Comment: Well wow I guess I took the long way around. Although I have two questions why the start integer is set to -99 and why you recommend to use break instruction? As far as I know break is used when you want to exit current method (switch in this example) but when one condition of the switch  will be true he will exit it anyway so I don't see the point of using it. Maybe I'm terribly mistaken :P

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html : Control flow continues with the first statement following the switch block. The break statements are necessary because without them, statements in switch blocks fall through: All statements after the matching case label are executed in sequence, regardless of the expression of subsequent case labels, until a break statement is encountered.

Comment: @brainless_bonobo do remember to "accept" whichever answer suits you.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of unnecessary statements. All you need to do is take the index of the given day, add the number of days, modulo 7, and get the resulting element. Java 11 solution:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> daysList = List.of("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What day is today:");
        String today = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("You want to know the day after how many days:");
        int numberOfDays = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("The day after " + numberOfDays + " will be "
                + daysList.get(((daysList.indexOf(today) + numberOfDays) % 7)));
     }
 }
```